# How to make table read only?

Tags: mysql, jpa, orm, spring-data

I have two tables in db with bi-directional many-to-one association. The problem is that I want write datas only in one table. Second must be read only. I searched but didn't find any solutions. I use spring data, jpa, eclipselink, mysql. Maybe someone knows how to solve this issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I solved it programmatically. In my entity class for read-only table I inserted @ReadOnly annotation and :

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Catalog.class, mappedBy="category", cascade={CascadeType.ALL},   fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Catalog> catalog;
```

and in target entity:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="cname", referencedColumnName="name")
private Category category;
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit permissions on a table you need to use [`REVOKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html):

> The REVOKE statement enables system administrators to revoke
>   privileges from MySQL accounts. Each account name uses the format
>   described in Section 6.2.3, “Specifying Account Names”.